# Batch: For loop parameter using variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a for loop that uses user input variables in it's parameter. Here is what I have:

```
@ECHO off
DEL "./positions.txt"
SET /P start_position= Please enter the start position:
SET /P end_position= Please enter the end position:
SET /P step_size= Please enter the step size:
FOR /L %%A IN (%start_position%,%end_position%,%step_size%) DO (
    ECHO %%A >> positions.txt
)
ECHO( & echo.Done! "positions.txt" was generated. & echo.
pause
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Here is what I get on the output:

```
>> Done! "positions.txt" was generated.
```

It runs, but skips over the for loop. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for /L` loops use the order start, step, end.

```
FOR /L %%A IN (%start_position%,%step_size%,%end_position%) DO (
    ECHO %%A >> positions.txt
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have C programming stuck in my head.